# O que significa "!" (Exclamação) antes de um trecho de código?

Tags: c#, operadores

Há muitas coisas básicas que eu não sei, por exemplo como ler exatamente essa exclamação da maneira que está colocada no trecho a seguir:

```
if (!(periodoAnterior.Equals(dataReader["NOMEPERIODO"].ToString()))){
    //...
}
```

Alguém pode me explicar? E aproveitando, esse Equals faz o mesmo que "==" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Qualquer coisa que você coloque dentro de um `if(aqui)` será transformada em `true` ou `false`. O corpo do `if` só executa se o resultado for `true`.

Vamos simplificar seu exemplo guardando o resultado do `Equals` numa variável:

```
bool resultado = periodoAnterior.Equals(dataReader["NOMEPERIODO"].ToString());
```

A variável `resultado` contém `true` ou `false`. Portanto temos duas opções para o `if`:

```
if (!(true)) {}
if (!(false)) {}
```

O que a exclamação `!` faz é inverter o valor de um booleano: `!true` (lê-se "not true") é `false`, e `!false` é `true`. Portanto, os resultados possíveis para o `if` serão:

```
if(false) {} // aqui o corpo nunca executa
if(true) {} // aqui o corpo executa
```

Assim, no seu código, o corpo do `if` só executa se o resultado de `periodoAnterior.Equals(dataReader["NOMEPERIODO"].ToString())` for `false`.

---

<sup>**Nota:** Sua dúvida quanto ao `Equals` mereceria uma pergunta à parte, mas provavelmente quem escreveu isso levou para o C# um vício de Java. Mais detalhes e exceções em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs</sup>

Comment: Legal, ganhei um downvote. Se tiver algo errado na minha resposta, por favor me avisem que eu corrijo.

Comment: Eu achei legal que o Joao Paulo viu que esta é a resposta mais completa, precisa e melhor escrita para todos.

Answer (score 19):

`!` é o operador de negação. Ele retorna o contrário da resolução da operação o qual ele precede.

Ou seja:

```
!true == false
!false == true
!(2 == 2) == false
!(2 == 1) == true
```

Comment: Nesse caso então se periodoAnterior.Equals(dataReader["NOMEPERIODO"].ToString())) é falso, usando a negação "se torna" verdadeiro?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Exatamente.

Comment: Ah, legal, a edição agora me exclareceu bem.

Comment: Marque a resposta do amigo como a solução do seu problema se não a pergunta continua em aberto.

Comment: Demora um tempo pra liberar a aceitação. Feito.